# Where does the "Hide Minions" extra come from?

Tags: mutants-and-masterminds-3e, hero-lab

The Hero Lab implementation of 3E *Mutants and Masterminds* includes a power Extra for the Summon power of "Hide Minions" with the following text:

> This extra hides your summoned minions. This is useful for heroes who summon many identical minions, or summon minions of a broad type. At rank 1, only one minion will be displayed. Rank 2 will hide all summoned minons [sic].

The thing is, I haven't found that Extra in any of the books I have access to (Core book, Power Profiles, Gadget Guide, Cosmic Handbook, Supernatural Handbook), and the Extra isn't tagged with a source. Does anyone know where this Extra might have come from? Lone Wolf generally only adds official material to their product, so I don't think they're making it up.

I also [asked on their forum](http://forums.wolflair.com/showthread.php?t=61280), but it's not always that active, and I think the guy who would have implemented it is no longer with the company.

Comment: Looks like a (poor) implementation of Subtle. Does the available documentation support that?

Comment: @ValhallaGH: I suppose one could argue that it's meant to be a "this power is hard to detect being used", but as it is, it reads as the minions getting an ersatz Concealment power.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I negatively criticized it. Assuming it is a Flat Extra, with two ranks, that lines up with Subtle, and making the minions hidden (and I'd argue they start off as hiding, per Stealth) is a kind of subtlety - but it isn't making the power subtle, which is what Subtle actually does.  It reads like a mess, and it certainly isn't core. I'd submit it to them as a bug and tell my player "no".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[charlieluce, on the Lone Wolf forums, pointed out](http://forums.wolflair.com/showpost.php?p=270840&postcount=2)

> Given that it's zero cost, I'm certain that this is just the way that Lone Wolf implemented a display customization for characters using the Summon Power.

With that hint, I looked at the code again. This is not meant as an actual power condition, and actually doesn't charge any points for either rank. Instead, it changes the output of Minion character sheets.